# gdkCursorNewFromPixmap example error

Tags: r, gtk, gdk

The example code from `gdkCursorNewFromPixmap` causes an error on Ubuntu with R 2.14.1 and `RGtk2` 2.20.25

Code:

```
library(RGtk2)

# This data is in X bitmap format, and can be created with the 'bitmap' utility in X11
cursor1_width <- 16
cursor1_height <- 16
cursor1_bits <- c(
  0x80, 0x01, 0x40, 0x02, 0x20, 0x04, 0x10, 0x08, 0x08, 0x10, 0x04, 0x20,
  0x82, 0x41, 0x41, 0x82, 0x41, 0x82, 0x82, 0x41, 0x04, 0x20, 0x08, 0x10,
  0x10, 0x08, 0x20, 0x04, 0x40, 0x02, 0x80, 0x01)
cursor1mask_bits <- c(
  0x80, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x60, 0x06, 0x30, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x18, 0x8c, 0x31,
  0xc6, 0x63, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x63, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x63, 0x8c, 0x31, 0x18, 0x18,
  0x30, 0x0c, 0x60, 0x06, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x80, 0x01)
 fg <- c(65535, 0, 0) # Red.
 bg <- c(0, 0, 65535) # Blue.
 source <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8) 
 mask <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8) 
 cursor <- gdkCursorNewFromPixmap(source, mask, fg, bg,0,0 )
```

Error:

```
Error in checkPtrType(source, "GdkPixmap") : 
  object of class GdkBitmap, RGtkObject isn't a GdkPixmap
Calls: gdkCursorNewFromPixmap -> checkPtrType
```

Comment: I changed the code: <pre>source <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8) mask <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8) cursor <- gdkCursorNewFromPixmap(source, mask, fg, bg,0,0 )<code> The last line causes a warning: <pre>Warning message: In .RGtkCall("S_gdk_cursor_new_from_pixmap", source, mask, fg, bg, : X11 protocol error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)<code> And the cursor when used is still the arrow: <pre>w <- gwindow() widget[["w"]]$setCursor(cursor)<code>

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to `GdkPixmap` not equal to `GdkBitmap`, use `gtk_pixmap_new` instead of `gtk_bitmap_create_from_data` (which btw is deprecated) (adapt these to the R namsing conventions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I changed the code:  

<pre>source <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8)
mask <- gdkPixmapNew(NULL, cursor1_width, cursor1_height, 8)
cursor <- gdkCursorNewFromPixmap(source, mask, fg, bg,0,0 )<code>

The last line causes a warning:  
<pre>Warning message:
In .RGtkCall("S_gdk_cursor_new_from_pixmap", source, mask, fg, bg,  :
  X11 protocol error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)<code>
 
And the cursor when used is still the arrow:  
 
<pre>w <- gwindow()
widget[["w"]]$setCursor(cursor)<code>

Comment: Make that comment an update to your question and I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: No you didn't, you added a comment to your own question. Edit the actual question, so code highlighting works.

Comment: Oops! OK, I changed the code in the question. Thanks for the tip!